# ３年間の、損失の繰越控除を postgresql にてクエリで実現するには？

Tags: sql, postgresql

下記で定義されるようなテーブルに、各年度(year)の収益(profit)が保持されています。
year は、ソートすると連続しているとします。(例: 2018, 2019, 2020; 反例: 2017, 2019, 2020)

```
CREATE TABLE profits
(
    year integer NOT NULL,
    profit integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT profits_pkey PRIMARY KEY (year)
);
```

このようなテーブルがあったとき、以下のデータを select したいです。

- 元の profit がすべて 0 以上ならば、`year, profit` がそのまま select
- profit が負の値である year については、その年の profit は 0 として select
- profit が負の値であった year(year0とする) は、その年以降の正の profit を持つものの中で、year0 から近い順に profit を相殺していく。相殺された year においては、完全に相殺されれば profit は 0 になり、相殺されきらなければその残りが profit となる。ただし、相殺は「元の year + 3」までしか起こらないとする。
- 一度相殺された profit を別の年に重複して相殺することはできない。

## 例1

```
# 元テーブル year: profit
2017: -20
2018: 10
2019: 30

==>
# 欲しいクエリ結果
2017: 0
2018: 0
2019: 20
```

## 例2

```
# 元テーブル year: profit
2016: -40
2017: -20
2018: -10
2019: -30
2020: 90

==>
# 欲しいクエリ結果
2016: 0
2017: 0
2018: 0
2019: 0
2020: 30
```

## 例3

```
# 元テーブル year: profit
2016: -10
2017: -10
2018: 10
2019: -20
2020: 40

==>
# 欲しいクエリ結果
2016: 0
2017: 0
2018: 0
2019: 0
2020: 10
```

## 質問

- これはどのようなクエリを書くと実現できますか？
- (できれば) 計算量的に最適化するには？
- (できれば) 一般 N 年間の通算に対しては？

## 背景

いわゆる、３年間の損失の繰越控除的な計算を、ふと、sql に落とそうと思った時に、どうやって実現するのか、何が計算量的に最適かが、自明ではないので、質問しています。

## 免責

数値計算の問題として定式化するためにいろいろ簡略化しており、実際の税務としてどうこう、という意図は一切ございません。

## 追記@2021/04/11

重複相殺をできないようにするケースを追加しました (相殺の定義が不明瞭でした)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

このようにすると、自分が欲しかった値が計算できることを確認しました。計算量は、`O(Y*N*logN)` (Y: 年の行数, N: 繰越年数) で求まっているはずです。(`logN`はソートが間に入るため)

```
WITH RECURSIVE
case1 (year, profit) as (
   values (2017, -20::bigint),
          (2018, 10::bigint),
          (2019, 30::bigint)
),
case2 (year, profit) as (
   values (2016, -40::bigint),
          (2017, -20::bigint),
          (2018, -10::bigint),
          (2019, -30::bigint),
          (2020, 90::bigint)
),
case3 (year, profit) as (
   values (2016, -10::bigint),
          (2017, -10::bigint),
          (2018, 10::bigint),
          (2019, -20::bigint),
          (2020, 40::bigint)
),
profits as (
   select * from case3 -- 試したい case を切り替える
),
acc as (
   select
     "year",
     greatest(profit, 0) as profit,
     case when profit >= 0 then '[]'::jsonb
          else json_build_array(json_build_object('year', year, 'value', profit))::jsonb
     end as residue
   from profits
   where year = (select min(year) from profits)

   union all

   select
     profits.year,
     calc.profit,
     calc.next_residue
   from acc
   inner join profits on acc.year + 1 = profits.year
   cross join lateral ( select greatest(profits.profit, 0) as gain, least(profits.profit, 0) as loss ) as t
   cross join lateral (
       with offset_calc1 as (
            select prev_residue.year, prev_residue.value as residue_before, least(gain + sum(prev_residue.value) over (order by year), 0)::bigint as acc_residue_after
            from jsonb_to_recordset(acc.residue) as prev_residue(year integer, value bigint)
            where profits.year - 3 <= prev_residue.year
       ),
       offset_calc2 as (
           select year, residue_before, acc_residue_after - lag(acc_residue_after, 1, 0::bigint) over (order by year) as residue_after
           from offset_calc1
       ),
       next_residue as (
           select year, residue_after as "value"
           from offset_calc2

           union all

           select profits.year, loss as "value"
       )
       select
         coalesce((select json_agg(next_residue)::jsonb from next_residue where "value" < 0), '[]'::jsonb) as next_residue, 
         (gain - (select sum(residue_after - residue_before) from offset_calc2))::bigint as profit
   ) as calc
)

select * from acc;
```

*実行結果*

```
 year | profit |                           residue                            
------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------
 2016 |      0 | [{"year": 2016, "value": -10}]
 2017 |      0 | [{"year": 2016, "value": -10}, {"year": 2017, "value": -10}]
 2018 |      0 | [{"year": 2017, "value": -10}]
 2019 |      0 | [{"year": 2017, "value": -10}, {"year": 2019, "value": -20}]
 2020 |     10 | []
(5 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

各行に過去3年分のprofitを LEFT JOIN で追加してあげれば計算できますね

```sql
    SELECT
      T1.year,
      GREATEST(T1.profit + T1.profit_1 + T1.profit_2 + T1.profit_3, 0)
    FROM (
      SELECT
        T1.year,
        T1.profit,
        COALESCE(T2.profit, 0) AS profit_1,
        COALESCE(T3.profit, 0) AS profit_2,
        COALESCE(T4.profit, 0) AS profit_3
      FROM
        profits T1
      LEFT JOIN
        profits T2 ON (T1.year -1 = T2.year)
      LEFT JOIN
        profits T3 ON (T1.year -2 = T3.year)
      LEFT JOIN
        profits T4 ON (T1.year -3 = T4.year)
    ) T1;
```

（ちょっと仕様がよくわからなかったので profit の計算は正しくないです）
（値さえ取得できてしまえば、あとは分岐するだけなので大丈夫でしょう）

結合を3回行いますが、必ず1行にしかマッチしないのでprofitテーブルの行数を越えることはなく、計算量的には大したことないと思います

この方法では一般 N 年間の通算はできないので、再帰共通テーブル式で実現してみます

```sql
    WITH RECURSIVE accumulated(current_year, year, profit) AS (
      SELECT
        year,
        year,
        profit
      FROM
        profits

      UNION ALL

      SELECT
        T1.year,
        accumulated.year,
        T1.profit + accumulated.profit
      FROM
        profits T1,
        accumulated
      WHERE
        T1.year = accumulated.current_year + 1
      AND
        T1.year <= accumulated.year + 3
    )
    SELECT
      current_year AS year,
      GREATEST(profit, 0) AS profit
    FROM (
      SELECT
        current_year,
        year,
        profit,
        rank() OVER (PARTITION BY current_year ORDER BY year) AS rank
      FROM
        accumulated
    ) T1
    WHERE
      rank = 1
    ;
```

（相変わらず「相殺」の意味するところが分からないので、計算は適当です）
N をパラメータ化できているので、自由に変更できます
この方式では N * (profitテーブルの行数) の大きさを持つ中間テーブルが発生します
処理が手続き式に記述されているので、条件の記述も簡単にできます
計算量についても、単純な N 回のループ計算ですから大して問題にはならないんじゃないでしょうか